# Add user from LDAP db to local linux group

Tags: users, group, ldap

My user to login to RHEL server is: **e5614**
I do not see that user in `/etc/passwd`.
But I do see it with `getent` command

```
getent passwd | grep e5614
e5614:x:613869764:10104:JohnJohn:/home/e5614:/bin/bash
```

I have a local group `docker` automatically created once the docker has been installed. Now I want to add my user to that group but I can't

```
usermod -aG docker e5614
usermod: user 'e5614' does not exist
```

How I can put my user in that local docker group so he can have all permissions like all other docker users? Thanks

Comment: Does the following question and answer address your issue: https://serverfault.com/questions/365752/how-to-add-ldap-user-to-existing-group ?